# Persistence unit name issue during deployment WildFly

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, wildfly

Stuck with some issue with my persistence module.

getting error like ***"Unexpected problem gathering statistics: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011477: Persistence unit 'EAR_FileName.ear/EJB_Module_Persistence.jar#MyPersistenceUnit' is not available"***

my persistence.xml file is located as highlighted below. please correct me if i am wrong - as per packaging structure persistence unit name starting with *EAR file name then my persistence module name then #unit name*,  which is absolutely right. and i am injecting my persistence unit in another ejb using PersistenceContext.

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="MyPersistenceUnit")
private EntityManager em;
```

could anyone suggest me what wrong i am doing here. i would appreciate any input/help you could provide on this.

here is below module structure of my project

```
EAR_FileName.ear
      |
      |---EJB_Module1.jar
      |
      |---EJB_Module_Persistence.jar
                    |
                    |---META-INF
                          |
                          |---persistence.xml
```

Here is my persistence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/MyTransactionDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>all class</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
                <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

P.S. using WildFly 8.1 as an application server.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that there is already a defect at the Wildfly-Tracker for this problem:

[WFLY-4908: Redeploy dependent ear fails with duplicate resource error for persistence unit](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4908)

There is as well a post at the Jboss-Forum:

[JBoss-Dev: Redeploy dependent ear fails with duplicate resource error for persistence unit](https://developer.jboss.org/message/935203#935203)

According to the defect description, the issue is fixed with Wildfly 10.1.0.CR1.